# Drag and Drop Multiple Objects in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement an application in which the user can drag and drop multiple objects inside a given area..I'm using html5 canvas tag to implement this..When there is only one object to drag and drop inside the canvas then the code is working fine, but when i try to drag multiple objects independently inside the canvas then i'm not getting the desired output..

Here is the working example of drag and drop of only one object with the draw function

http://jsfiddle.net/KZ99q/

```
function draw() {
clear();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
```

}

I thought adding more objects in draw() function will do so i added code for new objects in the draw() function like shown in this link

http://jsfiddle.net/KZ99q/1/

```
  function draw() {
  clear();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
  rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
  rect(x - 15, y - 15, 30, 30);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff550d";
  rect(x - 25, y - 25, 30, 30);
 ctx.fillStyle = "#800080";
  rect(x - 35, y - 35, 30, 30);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0c64e8";
 rect(x - 45, y - 45, 30, 30);
}
```

I can't seem to understand what changes do i need to make in the MyMove(), MyUp() and MyDown() functions to make the objects move independently of one another..
Please Help

Comment: @markE could you please look into this and please help me out??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When moving 1 (or more) shapes, the procedure is:

Create objects that define each shape:

```
// an array of objects that define different rectangles
var rects=[];
rects.push({x:75-15,y:50-15,width:30,height:30,fill:"#444444",isDragging:false});
rects.push({x:75-25,y:50-25,width:30,height:30,fill:"#ff550d",isDragging:false});
rects.push({x:75-35,y:50-35,width:30,height:30,fill:"#800080",isDragging:false});
rects.push({x:75-45,y:50-45,width:30,height:30,fill:"#0c64e8",isDragging:false});
```

In mousedown:

- get the current mouse position
- set the `isDragging` flag on any shape that is under the mouse
- save the current mouse position

In mousemove:

- get the current mouse position
- calculate how far the mouse has moved ( distance = newMousePosition-oldMousePosition )
- add the distance to the position of any shape that isDragging
- save the current mouse position
- redraw the scene with shapes in their new positions

In mouseup:

- clear all `isDragging` flags

Here's annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qm9Eb/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
window.onload=function(){

    // get canvas related references
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX=BB.left;
    var offsetY=BB.top;
    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    // drag related variables
    var dragok = false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    // an array of objects that define different rectangles
    var rects=[];
    rects.push({x:75-15,y:50-15,width:30,height:30,fill:"#444444",isDragging:false});
    rects.push({x:75-25,y:50-25,width:30,height:30,fill:"#ff550d",isDragging:false});
    rects.push({x:75-35,y:50-35,width:30,height:30,fill:"#800080",isDragging:false});
    rects.push({x:75-45,y:50-45,width:30,height:30,fill:"#0c64e8",isDragging:false});

    // listen for mouse events
    canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
    canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
    canvas.onmousemove = myMove;

    // call to draw the scene
    draw();

    // draw a single rect
    function rect(x,y,w,h) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fill();
    }

    // clear the canvas
    function clear() {
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    // redraw the scene
    function draw() {
        clear();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
        rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        // redraw each rect in the rects[] array
        for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
            var r=rects[i];
            ctx.fillStyle=r.fill;
            rect(r.x,r.y,r.width,r.height);
        }
    }


    // handle mousedown events
    function myDown(e){

        // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // get the current mouse position
        var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

        // test each rect to see if mouse is inside
        dragok=false;
        for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
            var r=rects[i];
            if(mx>r.x && mx<r.x+r.width && my>r.y && my<r.y+r.height){
                // if yes, set that rects isDragging=true
                dragok=true;
                r.isDragging=true;
            }
        }
        // save the current mouse position
        startX=mx;
        startY=my;
    }


    // handle mouseup events
    function myUp(e){
        // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // clear all the dragging flags
        dragok = false;
        for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
            rects[i].isDragging=false;
        }
    }


    // handle mouse moves
    function myMove(e){
        // if we're dragging anything...
        if (dragok){

          // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();

          // get the current mouse position
          var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

          // calculate the distance the mouse has moved
          // since the last mousemove
          var dx=mx-startX;
          var dy=my-startY;

          // move each rect that isDragging 
          // by the distance the mouse has moved
          // since the last mousemove
          for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
              var r=rects[i];
              if(r.isDragging){
                  r.x+=dx;
                  r.y+=dy;
              }
          }

          // redraw the scene with the new rect positions
          draw();

          // reset the starting mouse position for the next mousemove
          startX=mx;
          startY=my;

        }
    }

}; // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @varunsharma. Upload image from desktop is not part of the question.

Comment: Please note that it is no longer necessary to calculate the distance of the mouse movement in your code, the MouseEvent API contains two new properties `movementX` and `movementY` which provides this data to you. More information [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) and [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_mouseevent_movementx).

Answer (score -1):

```
<!-- HTML code for the button that opens the popup form -->
<button id="open-popup-btn">Open Popup Form</button>

<!-- HTML code for the popup form -->
<div id="popup-form-container" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background-color: #fff; padding: 20px;">
  <label for="name-input">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name-input"><br>

  <label for="email-input">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email-input"><br>

  <label for="phone-input">Phone:</label>
  <input type="tel" id="phone-input"><br>

  <button id="popup-save-btn">Save</button>
</div>

// JavaScript code to handle the button click event
const openPopupBtn = document.getElementById('open-popup-btn');
const popupFormContainer = document.getElementById('popup-form-container');
const popupSaveBtn = document.getElementById('popup-save-btn');

openPopupBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popupFormContainer.style.display = 'block';
});

popupSaveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const nameInput = document.getElementById('name-input').value;
  const emailInput = document.getElementById('email-input').value;
  const phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone-input').value;

  // Create a JSON object with the field values
  const formData = {
    name: nameInput,
    email: emailInput,
    phone: phoneInput
  };

  // Do something with the JSON object, like send it to a server or save it to local storage
  console.log(formData);

  // Hide the popup form after saving the data
  popupFormContainer.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).