# Canvas shape moving

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, shapes, drag

I have this code. This script can color in canvas like a paint application. All good. Now I put at the bottom of the script a function that add an image. I want to make that image movable, so I can drag it. I saw some scripts but I think I need to combine somehow with my function `findxy`, but I don't know how. If someone could help me.

```
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "white",
    y = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    teams();
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function color(obj) {
    switch (obj.id) {
        case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
        case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;
        case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
    }

}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.setDither = true;                    // set the dither to true    // set to STOKE
    ctx.setAntiAlias = true;                         // set anti alias so it smooths
    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        teams();
    }
}


function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
function teams() {
    var c=document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("topb");
    ctx.drawImage(img,103,80);
};
```

Comment: Can you please create a working jsfiddle with your full code..

Comment: Any image drawn on canvas cannot later be moved. Instead, you must clear the canvas and redraw the image in its new location. Here's a link to a relevant Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471968/cant-make-image-draggable-on-canvas/27475160#27475160