# Multiple image Drag and rotate in canvas html5

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas

I am uploading multiple image one by one in canvas. But problem is that, image not draggable. I seen one to drag option link, But i don't known how to use this one. 
https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

I will show you one screen shot:[image]

I want to every image draggable by mouse in canvas.
Code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Canvas Background through CSS</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    canvas, img { display:block; margin:1em auto; border:1px solid black; }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' id="fileUpload" />
<canvas id="canvas"  width="900" height="600" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></canvas>  


</body>
<script>

console.log("step 1");
function el(id){return document.getElementById(id);} // Get elem by ID
console.log("step 2");
var canvas  = el("canvas");
console.log("step 3");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
console.log("step 4");
function readImage() {
    console.log("step 5");
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
        console.log("step 6");
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           var img = new Image();
           img.onload = function() {
             context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
           };
   var b = img.src = e.target.result;
 console.log("step 7");
        };       
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}
console.log("step 8");
el("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
</script>
</html>
```

I  seen another link, but i cant able to  understand.
http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qm9Eb/

Because in this example box already in canvas.
Till now i have no idea about this problem. But something done by me, I'll show you code:[image]

```
<style>
            body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
            #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
        </style>
        <p>Resize the image using the 4 draggable corner anchors</p>
        <p>You can also drag the image</p>
        <input type="file" id="input"/>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=750 height=550></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <script>


            $(function () {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                console.log("ctx  " + ctx);
                var canvasOffset = $("#canvas").offset();
                var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
                var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

                var startX;
                var startY;
                var isDown = false;


                var pi2 = Math.PI * 2;
                var resizerRadius = 8;
                var rr = resizerRadius * resizerRadius;
                var draggingResizer = {x: 0, y: 0};
                var imageX = 50;
                var imageY = 50;
                var imageWidth, imageHeight, imageRight, imageBottom;
                var draggingImage = false;
                var startX;
                var startY;

                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    imageWidth = img.width;
                    imageHeight = img.height;
                    imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
                    imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight
                    draw(true, false);
                }

                var input = document.getElementById('input');
                input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles);

                function handleFiles(e) {
                    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
                    var img = new Image;
                    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
                    console.log("img.src  " + img.src);

                    img.onload = function () {
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
                    }
                }

                img.src = "https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.10.7/img/cake-cat-represntative-img/shapecakes.jpg";
                function draw(withAnchors, withBorders) {
                    // clear the canvas
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    // draw the image
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, imageX, imageY, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    // optionally draw the draggable anchors
                    if (withAnchors) {
                        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageY);
                        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageY);
                        drawDragAnchor(imageRight, imageBottom);
                        drawDragAnchor(imageX, imageBottom);
                    }
                    // optionally draw the connecting anchor lines
                    if (withBorders) {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(imageX, imageY);
                        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageY);
                        ctx.lineTo(imageRight, imageBottom);
                        ctx.lineTo(imageX, imageBottom);
                        ctx.closePath();
                        ctx.stroke();
                    }
                }

                function drawDragAnchor(x, y) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x, y, resizerRadius, 0, pi2, false);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }

                function anchorHitTest(x, y) {
                    var dx, dy;
                    // top-left
                    dx = x - imageX;
                    dy = y - imageY;
                    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
                        return(0);
                    }
                    // top-right
                    dx = x - imageRight;
                    dy = y - imageY;
                    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
                        return(1);
                    }
                    // bottom-right
                    dx = x - imageRight;
                    dy = y - imageBottom;
                    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
                        return(2);
                    }
                    // bottom-left
                    dx = x - imageX;
                    dy = y - imageBottom;
                    if (dx * dx + dy * dy <= rr) {
                        return(3);
                    }
                    return(-1);

                }


                function hitImage(x, y) {
                    return(x > imageX && x < imageX + imageWidth && y > imageY && y < imageY + imageHeight);
                }


                function handleMouseDown(e) {
                    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
                    draggingResizer = anchorHitTest(startX, startY);
                    draggingImage = draggingResizer < 0 && hitImage(startX, startY);
                }

                function handleMouseUp(e) {
                    draggingResizer = -1;
                    draggingImage = false;
                    draw(true, false);
                }

                function handleMouseOut(e) {
                    handleMouseUp(e);
                }

                function handleMouseMove(e) {

                    if (draggingResizer > -1) {

                        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

                        // resize the image
                        switch (draggingResizer) {
                            case 0: //top-left
                                imageX = mouseX;
                                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                                imageY = mouseY;
                                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                                break;
                            case 1: //top-right
                                imageY = mouseY;
                                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                                imageHeight = imageBottom - mouseY;
                                break;
                            case 2: //bottom-right
                                imageWidth = mouseX - imageX;
                                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                                break;
                            case 3: //bottom-left
                                imageX = mouseX;
                                imageWidth = imageRight - mouseX;
                                imageHeight = mouseY - imageY;
                                break;
                        }

                        // enforce minimum dimensions of 25x25
                        if (imageWidth < 25) {
                            imageWidth = 25;
                        }
                        if (imageHeight < 25) {
                            imageHeight = 25;
                        }

                        // set the image right and bottom
                        imageRight = imageX + imageWidth;
                        imageBottom = imageY + imageHeight;

                        // redraw the image with resizing anchors
                        draw(true, true);

                    } else if (draggingImage) {

                        imageClick = false;

                        mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
                        mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

                        // move the image by the amount of the latest drag
                        var dx = mouseX - startX;
                        var dy = mouseY - startY;
                        imageX += dx;
                        imageY += dy;
                        imageRight += dx;
                        imageBottom += dy;
                        // reset the startXY for next time
                        startX = mouseX;
                        startY = mouseY;

                        // redraw the image with border
                        draw(false, true);
                    }
                }


                $("#canvas").mousedown(function (e) {
                    handleMouseDown(e);
                });
                $("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
                    handleMouseMove(e);
                });
                $("#canvas").mouseup(function (e) {
                    handleMouseUp(e);
                });
                $("#canvas").mouseout(function (e) {
                    handleMouseOut(e);
                });


            }); // end $(function(){});
        </script>
```

Boy image is fix and car image is draggable because i am fetch direct in html canvas not uploading by user.(      img.src = "https://d3s16h6oq3j5fb.cloudfront.net/1.10.7/img/cake-cat-represntative-img/shapecakes.jpg";).

First boy image is upload by use. This is not draggable.

Please give me some idea to this problem.

Comment: There are no objects in canvas, it's like a painting. You'll have to write custom code to do something like detecting mouse click and repaint the images at new mouse coordinates until mouse release... The other draggable plugins works with actual DOM elements

Comment: @ Roko C. Buljan. In my code multiple image upload and put in the single canvas. Every image should be draggable. But  In this link ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100009/dragging-and-resizing-an-image-on-html5-canvas ) image not uploading. It is direct get in Java script from server. I want first upload the multiple image in canvas then every image should be draggable.

Comment: Your question is too broad. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471968/cant-make-image-draggable-on-canvas) to get the basics of hit-testing & dragging 1+ images on the canvas. If you still have trouble understanding here's a helpful [blog post by Simon Sarris](http://simonsarris.com/blog/510-making-html5-canvas-useful) .