# I want the elements on the canvas to be moved. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas element (square, line, triangle, etc.) I want to move these drawings in canvas within the width and height of the canvas element. There is an example here but the elements here are created manually. I am using the canvas from teledraw.js. And I make drawings with my tools.

example of this question => [Drag and Drop Multiple Objects in HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926028/drag-and-drop-multiple-objects-in-html5-canvas)

the library i use => https://github.com/lakenen/teledraw-canvas

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't magically guess what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

When animating elements on a canvas, you will first need to clear the canvas to later rerender the next position of the elements on it. I assume the library you use has some sort of animation function.